# how to packetize a file and send it using scapy in python?

Tags: python, networking, scapy

How to packetize a file (any files like audio, text, image, video and...) and send it on famous protocols like RTP using scapy in python?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read the [help pages](https://stackoverflow.com/help), take the [SO tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as this [question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

Activity need to be split into 2 parts

1. Reading the encoded data from different file format.

   audio - wav , amr, 3gp, mp4 etc.

   text - ascii, utf- 8, utf-16 etc.

   image - jpeg , gif , png etc.

   video - 3gp/mp4, avi, mkv etc.

   you can use [python ffmpeg](https://pypi.org/project/ffmpeg-python/) to read the data from these formats or use other library with similar functionality.
2. Pass the encoded data as the payload to the scapy and then add the RTP header.

   [read this blog](http://www.themoog.org/blog/wm8h7dl2glldz88pfd2kkg5fpfmjwf)